# C# Awesomium Web Brower Set DIV Contents

Tags: c#, dom, awesomium

I am making a program with C# that uses Awesomium for the interface.
When the program runs it generates a list, sometimes the list may be
quite large (5 - 6k lines). This list is only generated once and is
stored on the machine.

When the form loads it is a Web Browser control which loads a webpage
from the server displays it, the web page is essentially a replacement
for a standard GUI.

What i need to do is to take that list and display it in the Browser Control.
There is a Div with an ID where i need to display the list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using javascript and the `WebControl.ExecuteJavascript()` method. Here's an example that will target a div with an id of myDiv and add 30 child divs with an incrementing counter to it:

```
var script = "for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {" +
             "var newdiv = document.createElement('div');" +
             "var txt = document.createTextNode('This text was added to the DIV for i = ' + i + '.');" +
             "newdiv.appendChild(txt);" +
             "document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(newdiv); " +
             "}";

awesomiumControl.ExecuteJavascript(script);
```